# Can anyone hep me fixing blender?

Tags: windows, startup-file

Every time I open Blender the same project is opening, I don't know how I did this but I cant close the project and can't open a new project.

I haven't saved the project that opens anywhere, this window opens every time.

[image]

Comment: maybe you've accidentally saved a scene as default startup file, in that case go into File > Defaults > Load Factory Settings?

Comment: Hi.  Please use a descriptive title that reflects the content of the question.